# Using Visual Studio Live Share in combination with TFS

Tags: tfs, vscode-liveshare, visual-studio-liveshare

If the following happends:

1. Person Y has a problem with a piece of code
2. Person Y sends a live share code to person X
3. Person X edits person Y's code remotely through live share
4. Person Y checks this code into TFS

Who will be registerd as the author of that changeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS creates a changeset every time you do a check in.

All the included file changes from your workspace along with the comment, check-in notes, and links to related work items are stored on the server **as a single changeset** on your server.

Changeset owner/user is just the one who check files into TFS.

So in your case, it should be person **Y**  registerd as the author of that changeset

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, I was very curious after seeing this new feature from Microsoft